# Python Pandas Average and Sum conflicts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, mean

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: table]

The average and total rows are being calculated like so:

```
df1.loc["Average"] = df1.mean()
df1.loc["Total"] = df1.sum()
```

Now, I realized that the problem here is that the Average is calculating properly, but the sum is including the Average row as well, which is not what I want.

Ideally, I'd like to see something more like a single .loc row that has `sum()` applied to

```
`columns` ['Enageable R', 'R Responses', 'R Response Rate', 'Engageable Q',
                                'Q Responses', 'Q Response Rate']
```

and `mean()` applied to `columns ['R Response Rate', 'Q Response Rate']`

So I would love to see something like this:

| Brand | Engageable R | R Responses | Response Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brand1 | 34 | 34 | 100.00% |
| Brand2 | 34 | 34 | 100.00% |
| Brand3 | 34 | 34 | 100.00% |
| Total | 102 | 102 | 100.00% |

Comment: your target output does not match with your description I think

Comment: @ZLi I'm trying to get around sum() calculating with mean() included in the sum, which I would consider a conflict. Would you recommend a different description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) for processing both function separately and then add new rows by [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
df = df.append(df.agg(['sum','mean']).rename({'sum':'Total','mean':'Average'}))
```

If need procesing only some columns:

```
cols = ['Enageable R', 'R Responses', 'R Response Rate', 'Engageable Q',
                    'Q Responses', 'Q Response Rate']

df = df.append(df[cols].agg(['sum','mean']).rename({'sum':'Total','mean':'Average'}))
```

Comment: Awesome, this is the streamlined version of what I was looking for. I ended up creating a separate df, calculating into that 2nd df, and appending back into the first, which more computing intensive than your method, which achieves with less memory use and faster runtime. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a copy:

```
df2 = df1.copy(deep=True)

df2["Average"] = df1.mean()
df2["Total"] = df1.sum()
```

**EDIT**

your post is a little confused.

```
df1["Total"] = df1.sum()
df1["Average"] = df1[['R Response Rate', 'Q Response Rate']].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: It's a waste to use a copy, just exclude total in the second operation

Comment: So there is a huge difference between `df2["Average"]` and `df1.loc["Average"]`. What you're suggesting is creating a column called Average, where I'm trying to create a row. A copy will end up in the same spot I'm in right now, where the Total is calculating every row *including* the average row.

Comment: @Wilian I think you gave me a good idea, and I ended up making a blank df2, taking the df1.loc["Average"] and df1.loc["Total"] and then appending df2 to df1. The reason why the copy method didn't work is because total was summing all rows *including* the average row, or average row was averaging *all rows* including the total row. For example, look at my screenshot and look at `R Response Rate`. The Average row shows 14.03% [(38.04% + 0+0+18.08)/4]. But the Total row shows 70.15% [38.04% + 0+0+18.08+14.03]. I'm trying to avoid the total using the average row in the sum calculation.

Comment: @GH, this is a option: df['Average'], df['Total']= [df.mean(axis=1),df.sum(axis=1)]. Assign both columns at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found, with some credit due to @Wilian for the recommendation, although if there's a more efficient way to do this, let me know.

So I have a df1, and I created a blank df2 using:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Enageable R', 'R Responses', 'R Response Rate', 'Engageable Q',
                        'Q Responses', 'Q Response Rate'])
```

Then I filled df2 with:

```
df2.loc["Average"] = df1.mean()
df2.loc["Total"] = df1.sum()
```

Then I appended df2 to df1

```
df1 = df1.append(df2)
```

Which created the following:

[image: tablerevised]

So the sum and average columns are not including each other in the calculations of the other rows.